# Extraer datos concretos de una cadena string con php

Tags: php, string

Estoy intentando extraer de un string un valor en concreto, para poder guardarlo en una variable para posteriormente poder gestionarlo adecuadamente. Intente convertir el string en un array pero no funciono.

El string en cuestion es este

```
{"url":"https:\/\/s45-es.ikariam.gameforge.com\/index.php?action=loginAvatar&function=lobbyLogin&avatarId=5948&token=0c52e27a-c9fe-4d1e-ae32-9d2090b88b12"}
```

Y yo necesito simplemente el token que viene al final

```
0c52e27a-c9fe-4d1e-ae32-9d2090b88b12
```

La url no siempre tiene los mismos caracteres y el token tampoco, por lo que hacerlo contando caracteres no me sirve, ya lo probe.

Alguna idea de como se puede hacer?
Gracias!